# how to boot a U-boot / Uimage with qemu

Tags: arm, qemu, bootloader, u-boot

How do I boot an U-boot / Uimage?

in
/boot/uimage file
/boot-loader/u-boot bin

I tried to load it in arm and ppc but no luck
not sure what command i really need

i think i need to mount the folder as the folder has rest of the files it needs???

this is on a file in boot-loader

```
### console configuration ###
setenv stderr serial
setenv stdin  serial
setenv stdout serial
#setenv baudrate 115200
setenv console ttyS2
```

and

```
setenv loadaddr 0x80007fc0
setenv image_file /boot/uImage
```

I think it outputs what it's doing on serial console but not sure if it has shell

only evidence to suggest it has shell is in a code its asking about product type and S/N

can only assume thats set through serial